# Configuring Atlassian Crowd to process a domain redirect

Tags: single-sign-on, atlassian-crowd

- jira.service.bd
- confluence.service.bd
- crowd.service.bd

These should have the same SSO domain, so I set `.service.bd`

My crowd console URL:

http://crowd.service.bd:8095/crowd/console

I configure the custom domain in `/etc/hosts` as:

```
172.16.20.101 crowd.service.bd
```

If I configure the SSO domain as `crowd.service.bd`, I get Crowd login success.

If I use `.service.bd`, then the Crowd login will be a redirect. As this link [Crowd Login Redirected](https://confluence.atlassian.com/crowdkb/logging-in-to-crowd-keeps-failing-and-gets-redirected-back-to-the-login-page-296096569.html) said.

I suppose I should have something wrong about domain and subdomain. Should I configure second level domain on my host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

Change

- jira.service.bd
- confluence.service.bd
- crowd.service.bd

To

- jira.bdservice.com
- confluence.bdservice.com
- crowd.bdservice.com

And then set sso domain to .bdservice.com, then everything is OK.

I suppose crowd couldn't recognize `.bd` as top level domain.